# c - static & non-static variable in assmebly

Tags: c, assembly

**Question 1**: Is the following statement correct:

> In c file, a variable outside function which is not marked as static has scope from it's definition to end of the file.

**Question 2**: If the answer to question 1 is **true**, then when the c program compiled to assembly code, in which section does the variable metioned in question 1 stored?

@Edit:

> I ask this question because I am a little confused about variable marked with static and variable not marked with static. What is the underling different in assembly for this 2 kind of variable, where are they stored? If they both stored at the data section, then how does c make sure the variable marked with static is only visible to the file that define it.

---

@Answer:

> According to answer & comment of **@Vlad from Moscow**, the answer to question 1 is true, the answer to question 2 is "data section", and the reason that staic variable is only visible to the file defined it is that static variable has internal linkage to make sure it is not visible outside the compilation unit where it is declared.

Comment: The answer to the first question should be in any beginners book about C. The answer to the second can be found by going to your favorite search engine.

Comment: I don't understand why 2nd question is conditional to 1st being true.

Comment: @hyde Because I am a little confused about variable marked with static and variable not marked with static.

Comment: About Question 1, strictly speaking it is not true: Identifier's scope starts from first *declaration* in a compilation unit (and there can be arbitrarily many declarations of global variables), which is different from *definition* (of which there can be only one in the entire program for global variables). And for any global non-static variable, there's usually a declaration first, in an included header file.

Comment: @hyde Did you mean: the non-static variable outside function, are usually declared in a header file with extern, and then actual defined in a c file somewhere else, thus its lifecycle starts from the header file if the header file is included by some other file.

Comment: C standard does not have "variables", it has objects with storage duration, and identifiers in different scopes referring to those objects. "Variable" is combination of these, but distinction becomes important when you talk about things like life-cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the C Standard (6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers)

> 4 Every other identifier has scope determined by the placement of its
>   declaration (in a declarator or type specifier). If the declarator or
>   type specifier that declares the identifier appears outside of any
>   block or list of parameters, the identifier has file scope, which
>   terminates at the end of the translation unit.

It is the answer to your first question.

As for the second question then the variable is stored in data section and has static storage duration.

EDIT: variables that declared with storage class specifier `static` have internal linkage that is they are not visible outside the compilation unit where they are defined.

Comment: Note that question talks about *definition*, and your standard snippet talks about declaration... Also question talks about variable, your snippet talks about identifier.

Comment: @hyde Any variable has an identifier has not it?:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow thanks, does a static variable also stored in data section?

Comment: @Eric Wang Yes it is, but it has internal linkage that is it is not visible outside the compilation unit where it is declared.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thanks, that's what I need to know, PS. seems I asked the question in a bad way ...

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Does "variable" mean the identifier (which goes out of scope as described), or does it mean the object (which would in this case have static storage duration)? Not sure what the standard says about this, if anything.

Comment: @hyde The C Standard does not contain the definition of variable (or at least I did not find it) but the C++ Standard does contain "6 A variable is introduced by the declaration of a reference other than a non-static data member or of an object. The variable’s name denotes the reference or object."